# click event on option not working in safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I am re-creating my issue with the help of a very simple code (See below):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="a">
        <option class="b" value="opt1">opt1</option>
        <option class="b" value="opt2">opt2</option>
        <option class="b" value="opt3">opt3</option>
        <option class="b" value="opt4">opt4</option>
    </select>

    <script>
    $('.b').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

I expect that if I click an option (in the dropdown), the alert message should show. This is happening perfectly in Firefox but this is not working in Safari. Can someone please help me make it work in Safari as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few known workarounds:

- add `cursor:pointer` to your `<option>`s
- replace `.click(function(){})` with `.on('click touchstart', function(){})`

---

Another option (and, IMHO, the correct one) is to use the `oninput` event on the parent  `<select>`:

```
 $('select').on('input', function(){/* whatever */})
```

```js
$('select').on('input', function(){
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=""> Select something </option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's Apple's take on web security. Basically they ignore `click` events on elements that are not "valid" targets for click events. The simplest workaround is to give an element `cursor:pointer` to make it "valid" from their point of view. Or you could use `touchstart`, which is not exactly correct from usability point of view (but neither is `click`). It's a long story. :)